Count the number of Distributions (no adjacent objects should be identical) [General Approach without any sort of data]
This Question may already be on this platform,
I am asking the general approach for this problem if the no. of people were variable and no. of colors were variable.
Original Question -

Five person A,B,C,D and E are seated in a circular arrangement. If
each of them is given a hat of one of the three colors red, blue and
green ,then the number of ways of distributing the hats such that the
persons seated in adjacent seats get different colored hats is {ans is 30} {JEE Adv - 2019}

My Question :

m different persons are seated in a specific circular arrangement. If
each of them is given a hat of one of the n colors ,then the number of
ways of distributing the hats such that the persons seated in adjacent
seats get different colored hats is

I am really not sure how would I approach to this question, I did the original question by making cases with the fact that you can't use more than 2 hats of the same color.
Thank you in Advance!

The number of ways is $(n-1)^m+(-1)^m(n-1)$, as proven in this answer. There is also a more intuitive explanation given in this other answer.
